# Implement Mysql subquery satisfying two conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to obtain `flightno` if two conditions are correct ie, if there is a `flightno with airportcode ='something' AND if there is a flightno with airportcode='another'`.
if both these flightno's are same return the flightno.

i have tried

```
select flightno 
from airport 
where flightno = (
  select flightno from airport 
  where airport_code='blr') 
  AND 
  (select flightno from airport where airport_code='goy')
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt was close. Try this:

`select flightno
from airport
where flightno IN (select flightno from airport where airport_code='blr') 
  AND flightno IN (select flightno from airport where airport_code='goy')`

And in a more efficient way:

`select flightno
from airport as a
where exists (
  select 1 
  from airport as b 
  where a.flightno = b.flightno 
  and airport_code='blr'
  ) 
and exists (
  select 1
  from airport as c 
  where a.flightno = c.flightno 
  and airport_code='goy'
  )`

Comment: this works,also how can i check whether goy row comes after blr row in the condition

Comment: You will need a column with date/time/timestamp to compare on. Then add `and c.time_column < b.time_column` to the sub-query.

Comment: can you specify in which subquery we add this in your query?

Comment: Perhaps you should try it yourself - you might learn more that way. It is difficult to get more specific without more details about your data. For example, is `flightno` unique for each airport_code. Understanding the data is vital to be able to code the SQL correctly. You have not provided example table structures, or sample data.